# install emacs on ubuntu which support imagk

Tags: org-mode

I would like to install a emacs which support imagemagick by default. I try the default one with  `sudo apt install emacs` but it do not support imagemagick.

I run below command and found the output is nil.

```
(image-type-available-p 'imagemagick)
```

I try emacs-plus but it's not available with `sudo apt install emacs-plus` command.

Comment: Did you install imagemagick (`sudo apt install imagemagick`)?