# compile emacs 29.2 with imagemagick support

Tags: imagemagick

I run below script to compile 29.2, compile success but run below check still return nil.

os: ubuntu22.04
emacs: 29.2

```
(image-type-available-p 'imagemagick)
```

compile script:

```
cd emacs
./autogen.sh
./configure --with-native-compilation=aot --with-imagemagick --with-json \
    --with-tree-sitter --with-xft
make -j$(nproc)
sudo make install
```

Is imagemagack still support in 29.2?

```
$ sudo apt install libmagickwand-dev
[sudo] password for wjjsun: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libmagickwand-dev is already the newest version (8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.9).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 68 not upgraded.
```

config output:

```
checking for xcrun... no
checking for GNU Make... make
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking whether the compiler is clang... no
checking for compiler option needed when checking for declarations... none
checking whether gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for wchar.h... yes
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking for linux/fs.h... yes
checking for malloc.h... yes
checking for sys/systeminfo.h... no
checking for sys/sysinfo.h... yes
checking for coff.h... no
checking for pty.h... yes
checking for sys/resource.h... yes
checking for sys/utsname.h... yes
checking for pwd.h... yes
checking for utmp.h... yes
checking for util.h... no
checking for sanitizer/lsan_interface.h... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking for pthread.h... yes
checking for malloc/malloc.h... no
checking for sys/un.h... yes
checking for dirent.h... yes
checking for execinfo.h... yes
checking for stdio_ext.h... yes
checking for sys/vfs.h... yes
checking for sys/fs_types.h... no
checking for getopt.h... yes
checking for sys/cdefs.h... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for ieee754.h... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking for stdalign.h... yes
checking for stdbool.h... yes
checking for stdckdint.h... no
checking for sys/random.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking whether _XOPEN_SOURCE should be defined... no
checking for Minix Amsterdam compiler... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking whether gcc accepts -g3 -O2... yes
checking whether the compiler is clang... no
checking whether C compiler handles -Werror -Wunknown-warning-option... no
checking whether -Wno-missing-field-initializers is supported... yes
checking whether -Wno-missing-field-initializers is needed... no
checking whether -Wuninitialized is supported... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -fno-common... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wall... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Warith-conversion... no
checking whether C compiler handles -Wdate-time... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wdisabled-optimization... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wdouble-promotion... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wduplicated-cond... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wextra... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wformat-signedness... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Winit-self... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Winvalid-pch... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wlogical-op... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wmissing-declarations... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wmissing-include-dirs... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wmissing-prototypes... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wnested-externs... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wnull-dereference... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wold-style-definition... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wopenmp-simd... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wpacked... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wpointer-arith... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wstrict-prototypes... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wsuggest-attribute=format... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wsuggest-final-methods... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wsuggest-final-types... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wtrampolines... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wuninitialized... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wunknown-pragmas... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wunused-macros... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wvariadic-macros... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wvector-operation-performance... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wwrite-strings... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Warray-bounds=2... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wattribute-alias=2... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wformat=2... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wformat-truncation=2... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wshift-overflow=2... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wuse-after-free=3... no
checking whether C compiler handles -Wvla-larger-than=4031... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wredundant-decls... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wno-missing-field-initializers... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wno-override-init... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wno-sign-compare... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wno-type-limits... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wno-unused-parameter... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wno-format-nonliteral... yes
checking whether C compiler handles -Wno-bidi-chars... no
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking command to symlink files in the same directory... ln -s
checking for install-info... /usr/bin/install-info
checking for gzip... /usr/bin/gzip
checking for 'find' args to delete a file... -delete
checking for brew... no
checking for -znocombreloc... not needed
checking whether addresses are sanitized... no
checking for math library... -lm
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for machine/soundcard.h... no
checking for sys/soundcard.h... yes
checking for soundcard.h... no
checking for mmsystem.h... no
checking for _oss_ioctl in -lossaudio... no
checking for alsa >= 1.0.0... no
checking for ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE... yes
checking if Linux sysinfo may be used... yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking for net/if.h... yes
checking for ifaddrs.h... yes
checking for net/if_dl.h... no
checking for struct ifreq.ifr_flags... yes
checking for struct ifreq.ifr_hwaddr... yes
checking for struct ifreq.ifr_netmask... yes
checking for struct ifreq.ifr_broadaddr... yes
checking for struct ifreq.ifr_addr... yes
checking for struct ifreq.ifr_addr.sa_len... no
checking whether gcc understands -MMD -MF... yes
checking for X... libraries , headers 
checking whether malloc is Doug Lea style... no
checking for sbrk... yes
checking for __lsan_ignore_object... no
checking for fchmod... yes
checking for canonicalize_file_name... yes
checking for faccessat... yes
checking for realpath... yes
checking for lstat... yes
checking for readlinkat... yes
checking for explicit_bzero... yes
checking for memset_s... no
checking for fchmodat... yes
checking for lchmod... no
checking for fcntl... yes
checking for fdopendir... yes
checking for fstatat... yes
checking for fsync... yes
checking for futimens... yes
checking for getrandom... yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for mkostemp... yes
checking for pipe2... yes
checking for pselect... yes
checking for readlink... yes
checking for isblank... yes
checking for iswctype... yes
checking for strtoimax... yes
checking for symlink... yes
checking for localtime_r... yes
checking for timegm... yes
checking for utimensat... yes
checking for getdtablesize... yes
checking for futimes... yes
checking for futimesat... yes
checking for lutimes... yes
checking for getpagesize... yes
checking for working mmap... yes
checking for main in -lXbsd... no
checking for pthread library... -lpthread
checking for thread support... yes
checking whether X on GNU/Linux needs -b to link... no
checking for Xkb... yes
checking for XkbRefreshKeyboardMapping... yes
checking for XkbFreeNames... yes
checking for XrmSetDatabase... yes
checking for XScreenResourceString... yes
checking for XScreenNumberOfScreen... yes
checking for XDisplayCells... yes
checking for XDestroySubwindows... yes
checking X11 version 6... 6 or newer
checking for XICCallback.callback... yes
checking for librsvg-2.0 >= 2.14.0... yes
checking for libwebpdemux >= 0.6.0... no
checking for WebPGetInfo... no
checking for libwebpdemux >= 0.6.0 libwebpdecoder >= 0.6.0... no
checking for sqlite3_open_v2 in -lsqlite3... no
checking for MagickWand >= 7... no
checking for Wand >= 6.3.5 Wand != 6.8.2... yes
checking for MagickRelinquishMemory... yes
checking for MagickExportImagePixels... yes
checking for MagickMergeImageLayers... yes
checking for MagickAutoOrientImage... yes
checking for getaddrinfo_a in -lanl... yes
checking for gtk+-3.0 >= 3.10 glib-2.0 >= 2.37.5... no
checking for gtk+-2.0 >= 2.24 glib-2.0 >= 2.28... yes
checking whether GTK compiles... yes
checking whether GTK_TYPE_FILE_SELECTION is declared... yes
checking for gtk_file_selection_new... yes
checking for gtk_window_set_has_resize_grip... no
checking for malloc_trim... yes
checking for dbus-1 >= 1.0... no
checking for gio-2.0 >= 2.26... yes
checking whether GSettings is in gio... yes
checking for gobject-2.0 >= 2.0... yes
checking for lgetfilecon in -lselinux... yes
checking for gnutls >= 2.12.2... yes
checking for libsystemd >= 222... no
checking for jansson >= 2.7... no
checking for tree-sitter >= 0.20.2... no
checking for tree-sitter >= 0.6.3... no
checking sys/inotify.h usability... yes
checking sys/inotify.h presence... yes
checking for sys/inotify.h... yes
checking for inotify_init1... yes
checking for XRenderQueryExtension in -lXrender... yes
checking for cairo >= 1.8.0... yes
checking for freetype2... yes
checking for fontconfig >= 2.2.0... yes
checking for FT_Face_GetCharVariantIndex... yes
checking for libotf... no
checking for harfbuzz >= 0.9.42... yes
checking X11/Xlib-xcb.h usability... no
checking X11/Xlib-xcb.h presence... no
checking for X11/Xlib-xcb.h... no
checking X11/xpm.h usability... yes
checking X11/xpm.h presence... yes
checking for X11/xpm.h... yes
checking for XpmReadFileToPixmap in -lXpm... yes
checking for XpmReturnAllocPixels preprocessor define... yes
checking for jpeglib 6b or later... -ljpeg
checking for lcms2... yes
checking for library containing inflateEnd... -lz
checking for dladdr... yes
checking for dlfunc... no
checking for gcc_jit_context_acquire in -lgccjit... no
```

Comment: When you run the `configure` command, you will get output describing what features are and are not available ... that script may not be able to find the `imagemagick` installation on your computer, or you may not have it properly installed, or it may be missing entirely.  Feel free to add the output of the `configure` script to your question body ...  If you need help installing the `imagemagick` package on your computer, add details to the question body such as the operating system and version, etc.

Comment: FWIW, the OP [asked similar question 2 days ago](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/80634/install-emacs-on-ubuntu-which-support-imagk) and completely ignored a question of whether they even have `imagemagick` installed, which is relevant both here and there.

Comment: paste the output log, not found imagemagick.